# I often use "now itself"

Tags: spoken-english

I would like to understand whether the use of phrase " now itself" is correct or not. For instance, I use "i will get started with the task now itself". If it's not correct, how would I say something that I have started with immediately after.

Comment: *I will get started now with the task itself* would be fine, but not **now itself**  You might say that after having described some preparatory actions.

Comment: Normal in Indian English - unknown elsewhere. (See my comment on Eran's answer).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"now itself" is not used in English.

You should use "right now" or "immediately" instead.

"I will get started with the task right now."

"I will get started with the task immediately."

Comment: Wrong. "Now itself" is used in English, but only in Indian English. There are 99 instances of "now itself" in the GloWbE corpus, most of them not in this meaning (rather "itself" refers back to the subject). But nearly all of the 38 instances from India, Pakistan, Sri Lanka, and Malaysia are used in this way.

Comment: @ColinFine Thanks for the correction. I have very little knowledge (or to be exact, no knowledge) in Indian English. I think it's likely, though, that the OP didn't ask about Indian English.

Comment: I know only that I have encountered it more than once from Indian correspondents. Also "today itself", where 53/62 instances on GloWbE are from India, Pakistan, Sri Lanka, Bangla Desh, and Malaysia. I think it's likely that the OP speaks Indian English, though they might well have been taught the vile and abusive idea that if something is only in Indian English then it's "not correct".